# How to refetchQueries a query having an args option

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I would like to know how to pass an argument during a `refetchQueries` in Apollo.

Code:

```
submitForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.addAppleMutation({
            variables: {
                        color: "red"
                        weight: "0.33"
            },
            // stuck here
            refetchQueries: [{ query: loadApplesQuery, variables: {//argument i want to pass} }]
        })
    }
```

My query:

```
const loadApplesQuery = gql`
    query($id: ID) {
        apple(id: $id) {
            color
            size
            id
        }
    }
`
```

Comment: `refetchQueries: (mutationResult) => [{ query: loadApplesQuery, variables: { id: mutationResult.blahblah  } }]`  https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations

Answer (score 3):

Yeah you can do this, you can also have a look at the same scenario that you want to tackle at

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo#graphql-mutation-options-refetchQueries

so for example you can do this with High Order Component (HOC), you can do something like this

```
const loadApplesQuery = gql`
    query($id: ID) {
        apple(id: $id) {
            color
            size
            id
        }
    }
`;

const addAppleMutation = gql`
    mutation($apple: Apple) {
        addApple(Apple: $apple)
    }
`;

export default graphql(addAppleMutation, {
  name: 'addAppleMutation',
  options: {
    refetchQueries: (mutationResult) => [{
        query: loadApplesQuery,
        variables: {
          id: mutationResult.id,
        }
      }]
  },
})(MyComponent);
```

and then in the submitForm method you can do something like this

```
submitForm(e) {
   this.props.addAppleMutation({ variables : { color: 'green', size: 'small'}});
}
```

Hopefully that will help you.

Comment: Is there a way to see the mutationResult? for debugging purposes

Comment: yeah it will be logged to console like ```console.log(mutationResult)```

Comment: Tried refetchQueries: (murationResult) => console.log(mutationResult) and it sent back an object data: { addApple: {id: '231', color: 'green', size: 'small'} }. But when I call id: mutationResult.id, it's not working

Comment: I think you are accessing it like this ```mutationResult.id``` instead it should be like this ```mutationResult.data.id``` so kindly use this to log ```console.log(mutationResult.data.id)```

Hopefully it will work for you.